# how to make rails external database calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

So i'd like to be able to add an external database to my `config/database.yml`   Then model one table from it.

Is this possible? I haven't been able to figure out how.

"Connection to multiple databases in different models

Connections are usually created through `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and retrieved by `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. All classes inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` will use this connection. But you can also set a class-specific connection. For example, if `Course` is an `ActiveRecord::Base`, but resides in a different database, you can just say `Course.establish_connection` and `Course` and all of its subclasses will use this connection instead.

This feature is implemented by keeping a connection pool in `ActiveRecord::Base` that is a Hash indexed by the class. If a connection is requested, the retrieve_connection method will go up the class-hierarchy until a connection is found in the connection pool. "

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, define the connection information in database.yml:

```
my_external_db:
  adapter: mysql
  username: ...
  ....
```

Then, create the model and connect it to the external db

```
class MyExternalModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:my_external_db)
  set_table_name 'my_external_table'
end
```

Comment: do i have to close the connection afterwards?

Comment: @Kirby: I don't think you'd want to do that, or else rails would have to open a new connection for each request. Here it's only done once when the server boots.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! was trying myself to connect my rails app to an external database. very helpful.

Comment: Be careful if using Heroku. Heroku throws away the database.yml file,  so you'll have to find somewhere else to define the connection info.

Answer (score 2):

`set_table_name` is removed, so instead, you should use: `self.table_name`