# How to queries from database without model in Rails3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, model

How can i solve this problems if i dont't use injection sql command in controller?

More details[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4727470/how-to-make-rails-external-database-calls

Basically, the point is that you can define the connection to the other database in database.yml. ActiveRecord::Base will inherit from one by default, but you can use the `establish_connection` method to connect to the other database that you've configured for a given model.

Then you can use the ActiveRecord API (e.g. find_by_sql) to query the other database.

Comment: I thought 'establish_connection' is a good idea to solved. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't (or at least shouldn't) get around using at least ActiveRecord models and querying them using `find_by_sql`.

Refer to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql

Comment: um mayby 'Rails's creator' get read this and solved this problem soon hahaha , Thank for your answer but i still to solve it except sql command.

Comment: find_by_sql is one of solution you can do then you want to queries other tables that still in rails project (the same database) and will not work within queries to another database.