# Extract data from a remote database (MySQL) in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to connect my app to a remote database and extract this data for plotting purposes.

Let's suppose my database structure is like that (exactly how it is depicted by MySQL Workbench):

```
All_clients
 Tables
   client_products
     Columns
       number
       article
```

and I want to extract the entity `number`.

I am very new working with models and databases in Rails and I have no found info. in internet.

Question: So, assuming that the connection to the external DB is already established. How can I access the entity `number` in my remote database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make rails external database calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727470/how-to-make-rails-external-database-calls)

Comment: No, sorry. See question again.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a very basic question. All tutorials explain how to create a database in the local machine and to create the database. If this is very basic, why don’t you help answering my question? We are here after all to learn.

Comment: If this question is not a basic question about how to create a very basic ActiveRecord model, then it is not clear what you're asking. Have you ever get through any tutorial to the end, or did you stopped after database creation? SO is not for learning framework basics, it is for solving real-life programing problems.

Comment: Of course I know how to create a model and database from zero in Rails. In this case, I want to grap data in a remote DB which is already which data. This is a real life problem. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your question is about,

How to access the DB/tables from rails, or accessing an external database from rails.

So here goes,

For the first part, rails uses ORM (object Relational Mapping) to connect to tables (via ActiveRecord)

As an example if you want to access a table called `users` you should mave a model called `User` (by default) [read more about the active record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

To answer the second part, If you want to connect to an external host, you can give the host and port in your `database.yml` file. One example would be [connecting an RDS DB like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.rds.html)

And if you want to connect to a external DB to access data, (while having your primary DB), thats not a good idea. You should always access external DB/ Data sources via their own API's

HTH