# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError when trying to access data from remote MySql database in a Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a Rails app that will be using an existing remote MySQL database. I was able to set up the `database.yml` correctly and connect to the database. I can access the database tables in my rails console by creating the model of the same name, but without executing any migrations. However, in the browser I keep getting the following error:

**`ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError`**
`Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

To make sure I've covered all my bases, I've also added `establish_connection(:development)` and `self.table_name = 'users'` to my `user.rb` file, but no luck as yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

For reference, I've followed these resources:
 - https://hackhands.com/ruby-rails-tutorial-creating-rails-instance-existing-mysql-db/
 - [how to make rails external database calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727470/how-to-make-rails-external-database-calls)

Also, I'm using Rails 4.2.4 and ruby 2.2.3 for this app.

Comment: you simply need to run `rake db:migrate` commad

Comment: @dimakura the tables already exist and are populated in the remote db. They are already being used by a php app. Will this affect the existing tables? or will it simply execute a schema dump and not create new tables/reset existing tables?

Comment: Fixed it. Created migration file, commented out everything within `change` before running `rake db:migrate`. It dumps the schema, and adds a version to it. No existing tables are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no schema migration table. Even if there are no migrations you need a blank one. As said before and in the error message run rake db:migrate and the table should be created.

That is assuming you have write access.

The following should work to create it if rake db:migrate doesn't work for some edge case reason. This is just from PGAdmin table information window.

```
CREATE TABLE schema_migrations
(
  version character varying(255) NOT NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE schema_migrations
  OWNER TO whatever~owner;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_schema_migrations
  ON schema_migrations
  USING btree
  (version COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```